# How to fetch data from two different collections without getting badstate element error? flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have gone through a lot of links in stackoverflow but nothing matches my requirement. below is my code

```
StreamBuilder equipmentListStreamBuilder(collectionName, eType) {
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection(collectionName)
      .where("equipmentType", isEqualTo: eType)
      .where("geopoint", isGreaterThan: lesserGeopoint)
      .where("geopoint", isLessThan: greaterGeopoint)
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return (!snapshot.hasData)
        ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
        : Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 10),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  child: Text(
                    "${snapshot.data.docs.length} Equipments in ${addressNotifier.value.cityID} (within $distance km)",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate:
                      const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    mainAxisExtent: 325,
                  ),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    DocumentSnapshot data = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                    equipDistance = MapUtils.calculateDistance(
                        data["geopoint"].latitude,
                        data["geopoint"].longitude,
                        addressNotifier.value.geoPoint.latitude,
                        addressNotifier.value.geoPoint.longitude);
```

My error occurs in the following code where I navigate between two collections in firestore. if isSell is true it should go to a particular collection and fetch expected price. If it is false it should pick additional price from another collection. When I switch between tabs, I get the error for a second and then it loads correctly.

```
                    return EquipmentGrid(
                      modelName: data['brand'] + " " + data['modelName'],
                      equipmentGeopoint: data['geopoint'],
                      ownerID: data["ownerID"],
                      additionalPrice: isSell
                          ? data["expectedPrice"].toString()
                          : data["additionalPrice"].toString(),
                      hp: data["features"]["hp"],
                      isSell: isSell,
                      eID: data.id,
                      uID: widget.myUID,
                      distance: equipDistance,
                    );
                   
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
    },
  );
  }
```

I went through some examples where they ask to check if the data exists using in line if condition. I tried something like this

```
 additionalPrice: isSell
                          ? data["expectedPrice"].toString().isNotEmpty
                              ? data["expectedPrice"].toString()
                              : null.toString()
                          : data["additionalPrice"].toString().isNotEmpty
                              ? data["additionalPrice"].toString()
                              : null.toString(),
```

But it returns null for all the grid. How to get the price without getting bad state element error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for the same...
Using the switching option in the grid causes the problem.. Instead I changed my code as follows...

```
       String price = "";
                    if (isSell) {
                      price =
                          data.data().toString().contains('expectedPrice')
                              ? data["expectedPrice"].toString()
                              : "0";
                    } else {
                      price =
                          data.data().toString().contains('additionalPrice')
                              ? data["additionalPrice"].toString()
                              : "0";
                    }
                    return EquipmentGrid(
                      modelName: data['brand'] + " " + data['modelName'],
                      equipmentGeopoint: data['geopoint'],
                      ownerID: data["ownerID"], additionalPrice: price,
                      // additionalPrice: isSell
                      //     ? data["expectedPrice"].toString()
                      //     : data["additionalPrice"].toString(),
                      hp: data["features"]["hp"],
                      isSell: isSell,
                      eID: data.id,
                      uID: uid,
                      distance: equipDistance,
                    );
```

This works perfectly